# Does invisible controls slow down your app rendering?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Good day, In my program I have so much controls, and I question myself that if I put labels with the property visible = false;, this labels affect in the render time of my form.

Comment: Invisible controls are being drawn but is not visible.

Comment: They are not being rendered, so not slowing down rendering. There is a difference between updating and rendering.

Comment: @ForeverZer0  I mean That if The invisible labels affect in the time that takes to load a window and it's controls

Comment: Unless you are drawing thousands of labels, or using some custom `OnPaint` override slowing down the drawing, there no real significant difference between drawing or not-drawing a label that's going to change the loading speed of your window. Are you having issues loading the window is the more important question.

Comment: @ForeverZer0  Yes, It's a really heavy window, so so i di this question

Comment: Slow to load initially, or slow to respond when interacting with it? If only initial load, the painting is likely not the issue. I would strongly suggest some example code to show us, or more detail in what the problem is so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question: The speed of loading practically does not change, because all visible and invisible objects will be loaded into memory.

To prove it with example is very simple: Insert on the form PictureBox and set image with  ~ 5mb size (to demontrate) and run the application with both values of PictureBox visible (true,false) [note memory size]. Also before inserting PictureBox and  runing  applicaton, note memory size (to assess the difference).

In order to avoid this, after the "rendering" you can create controls at Run Time. ([How to programmatically add controls to Windows forms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319266/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-windows-forms-at-run-time-by-u) and [it](http://google.com/search?q=how%20create%20dynamic%20controls%20at%20runtime%20vb.net%20%20c%23))

Answer (score 0):

There are two step for controls to be shown on UI

1. Initializing object into memory
2. Rendering Control on UI

When you set a control as invisible, the second one will not take part.
You can test this with a fast changing control, like loading a new photo into a PictureBox every 10ms.

Comment: But It affects un it's speed?

Comment: It will affect your performance specially if first step is a big one. For strandard contr this is not a big one and you can ignore it.